# Show label in the final of each trajectory - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-text

I'm aplying clustering to longitudinal data. This type of data is basically trajectories produced by the data over time. I want to show the label/text in the end of each trajectory, but I can only show them all at all points.

For the following example, there are trajectories for some european countries. This is what I get. 
[image]

But I want to show the country name only once in the end of its trajectory! Is it possible?

This is my code

```
data_long <- reshape(data_class, varying=c(2:61),
                     direction="long", timevar="time",
                     idvar=c("datapr.Country.Region", "Clusters"), v.names="value") #reshaping wide to long format
data_long
data_long$Clusters <- as.factor(data_long$Clusters)

cnames <- row.names(data_long)
p <- ggplot(data = data_long, aes(x = time, y = value, group = datapr.Country.Region,colour = Clusters,label=cnames))
p + geom_line() +geom_text()
```

Comment: Subset the data. E.g. using `dplyr`, use `+ geom_text(data = . %>% group_by(datapr.Country.Region) %>% slice(n())`.

Comment: That's a good idea but the code you said is not working unfortunately

Comment: Why do you take cnames as the row.names of the data frame and proceed to use it as label? It going to be some weird label.

Comment: and can you provide an example dataset?